# RemoteCertificateNameMismatch when connecting to Amazon S3 compatible storage

Tags: amazon-s3, .net-core, amazons3client

I'm getting a `System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch` while connecting to Amazon S3 compatible storage service for downloading. This project was working fine a few months ago, and sudenly has started to fail, without any changes in code.

I've found that AmazonS3Client is prepending the bucket name to the URL, thus causing the SSL protocol to fail. I've traying upgrading the AWSSDK.S3 lib to latest version without success.
Anyone have a clue about how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records in case it can help someone else, I found what should be the right config of S3 client to work:

```
var config = new AmazonS3Config
{
    ServiceURL = Configuration.Host,
    UseHttp = true,
    ForcePathStyle = true,
    SignatureVersion = "V4"
};

var client = new AmazonS3Client(configuration.Value.AccessKey,
    configuration.Value.SecretKey,
    config
);
```

Comment: The only relevant setting is ForcePathStyle, as having this as false will generate urls that differ from the one in the SSL certificate.